# How did human beings come to realize the concept of counting numbers?

Tags: mathematics

Human beings keeping count is as old as recorded history; however, how did humans first think about keeping documentation and counting numbers? Is there any defined period in history where numbers were written about, where early scholars and scientists discoursed about the origins of counting? Specifically, how did we as a species come to realize that counting is possible and useful in everyday life?

If any links or references exist to answer this question, please post an answer below. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Still useful [Abraham Seidenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Seidenberg)'s [The Ritual Origin of Counting (1962)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133226?seq=1)

Comment: There was no such period, "scholars and scientists" are much more recent than counting, and even written language is. We did not come to realize that counting is useful "as a species", already [fish can count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sense_in_animals), and human counting artifacts date to prehistoric times, e.g. the [Ishango bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishango_bone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that we don't know how human beings came to realize the concept of counting numbers. The discovery of counting is lost in prehistory. Most likely humans are born with the capacity to count, given that scientists have established that other species like apes or parrots can count. This would be the numerical analogue to Chomsky's notion of an innate grammar.